# Burning tokens and reducing supply

Tags: solidity

I am trying to modify an existing contract that only reduces token circulation. It doesn't reduce supply.

I added the `_tTotal = _tTotal.sub(burnAmt);` line that reduces total supply, but someone was saying that I should also reduce the `_rTotal`, `_tOwned` and `_rOwned`.

The contract is deployed here: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xEFD27A640223394cE0159568B94e5c82099B667A#code

Can anybody help me figure out how to get this done? I don't really understand what `_rTotal`, `_tOwned` and `_rOwned` do.

```
function _tokenTransfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) private {
    if(_isExcludedFromFee[sender] || _isExcludedFromFee[recipient]){
        removeAllFee();
    }
    
    //Calculate burn amount and charity amount
    uint256 burnAmt = amount.mul(_burnFee).div(100);
    uint256 charityAmt = amount.mul(_charityFee).div(100);

    if (_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
        _transferFromExcluded(sender, recipient, (amount.sub(burnAmt).sub(charityAmt)));
    } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
        _transferToExcluded(sender, recipient, (amount.sub(burnAmt).sub(charityAmt)));
    } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
        _transferStandard(sender, recipient, (amount.sub(burnAmt).sub(charityAmt)));
    } else if (_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
        _transferBothExcluded(sender, recipient, (amount.sub(burnAmt).sub(charityAmt)));
    } else {
        _transferStandard(sender, recipient, (amount.sub(burnAmt).sub(charityAmt)));
    }
    
    //Temporarily remove fees to transfer to burn address and charity wallet
    _taxFee = 0;
    _liquidityFee = 0;

    //burn
    _transferStandard(sender, address(0), burnAmt);
    _tTotal = _tTotal.sub(burnAmt);
    
    _transferStandard(sender, charityWallet, charityAmt);

    //Restore tax and liquidity fees
    _taxFee = _previousTaxFee;
    _liquidityFee = _previousLiquidityFee;

    if(_isExcludedFromFee[sender] || _isExcludedFromFee[recipient])
        restoreAllFee();
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, as in my opinion it requires more focus. In my opinion, you are asking "I have this complicated contract and I want to change its functionality, how should I do it?". That's a rather broad question and answering that isn't easy (unless you happen to know that contract by heart from somewhere)

Comment: Well yeah. Anything that you don't know is complicated. But closing a question that might help me and others learn stuff isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tTotal`, `rTotal`, `tOwned` and `rOwned` are used in safemoon contract to calculate the balance of the users and the reflections they should get ( more details here https://reflect-contract-doc.netlify.app/, be careful : may contain complicated maths) . I'd **STRONGLY** recommend not messing around too much with those values unless you know what you're doing, because you can really well end up completely fucking up the way the contract calculates the users balances, and having it producing complete nonsense results, which would definitely be the case with your code as it is right now (you're modifying `tTotal` without touching `rTotal`, meaning that the total supply and the number used to calculate reflections will be slowly drifting out of sync with each transactions, and you'll end up giving as reflections tokens that doesnt exist).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for answering. That link is a bit too much for me but I will try to understand it. Maybe I'll just remove the burn functionality, but it would be really helpful. Do you know any contract that has reflections, burn, charity and automatic liquidity pool? Would love to compare codes.

Comment: So ... I'm thinking that the first thing to do is this: `_rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal.sub(burnAmt)));` modify the _rTotal based on the new supply.

Comment: Nop. You have to derive rBurnAmt from burnAmt (use the `getValues` function) and then substract that number to rTotal. If you're going to change stuff like that make sure you do extensive testing though cause its easy to fuck something up